# surface integrals orientation. when is it positive or negative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals, orientation

For this question below, I don't understand what they're asking. what does it mean to find the net flow rate upward through the surface? How do I know if I need to put a negative before computing the surface integral? Also, I've only encountered questions where they ask about the net flow out of the surface ( positive orientation ) and the net flow inside the surface ( negative orientation). but here, they ask for an upward net flow, which seems ambiguous. like does that mean the normal is pointing outward or inward? In brief, im just not sure how to figure out when is the orientation positive or negative
[image].

Comment: Yes that sounds ambiguous. Inward/outward are parallel to the normal vector of the surface and only differ by the sign. Upward/downward could as well mean flows parallel to the $z$-axis in which case we can simplify the surface to a disk in the $x,y$-plane. Since this is homework I guess however that it is not what they meant. I recommend to submit both solutions.

Comment: I think that "upward" means that the $z$-component of the any normal vector to the surface $\mathbf{n}$ should be $\geq0$.

Comment: Could be. @user20194358 : can you see immediately (without doing a calculation) that the two solutions I suggested must be different. Hint: divergence of $\mathbf F$.

Comment: @KurtG . To be honest, I don't see why. I only understand when it comes to normal pointing outward or inward a surface.

Comment: @RobertZ this makes sense. since in the answer key ( this is a practice problem), when they found the normal vector, they saw the z component was "r" which is always positive, thus, they concluded the orientation was already positive. but I don't understand. like if the normal always have positive z component, they how are we going to calculate the flux in every single position ?

Comment: The boundary of the surface is given by the equation $f(x,y,z)=1$ where $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z\,.$ In other words, $\partial S$ is a level set of the function $f$. Do you see that the gradient of $f$ is parallel to the normal vector $\mathbf{n}$? If so calculate it, normalize it to length one and, if necessary, give it a sign so that it points "upward".

Comment: @KurtG. okok this makes sense. thank you

Comment: Sorry. One mistake: I think that we should take $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z\,.$